# Objects won't spawn at correct location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate cubes in a random pattern.

First, a cube is spawned into the world. Then a random number is generated. This number decides where the next cube is spawned. Let's call it cube1 After cube1 is spawned, cube2 should use the position of cube1 to spawn but it still uses the position of the original cube.

I can't understand why.

I have already tried using Debug.Log to view different positions but I can't seem to get it working no matter what I try.

```
public class GenerateDungeon: MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] cells;
    public int number = 0, i = 0;

    public void Start()
    {
        Instantiate(cells[i], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);

        while(i < 2)
        {
            number = Random.Range(1, 5);

            i++;

            if (number == 1)
            {
                Instantiate(cells[i], cells[i - 1].transform.position + new Vector3(0, 4, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            else if (number == 2)
            {
                Instantiate(cells[i], cells[i - 1].transform.position + new Vector3(4, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            else if (number == 3)
            {
                Instantiate(cells[i], cells[i - 1].transform.position + new Vector3(0, -4, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            else if (number == 4)
            {
                Instantiate(cells[i], cells[i - 1].transform.position + new Vector3(-4, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any error messages but it's not working the way I intended it to.

Comment: you are using the same random range for both calls so it is possible for it to use the same number for more than 1 cube.

Comment: " but it's not working the way I intended it to.", that's not a very good diagnostic for us to help?

Answer (score 0):

When calling Instantiate, the first argument is the object to be copied, not the destination reference it's copied to.

So, what you probably want is to store a reference to the source object:

```
public GameObject CubeToCopy;
```

And then when instantiating, you want to copy each one into the array like so:

```
cells[i] = Instantiate(CubeToCopy, [...]);
```

That way, the 'cells' array is storing the objects you're actually instantiating, and your position logic should start working properly.